# Why does Android Studio lint not recognize my minSdkVersion

Tags: java, android, android-studio, lint, android-min-sdk

Android Studio (version 4.1.1) is displaying warnings in my xml layout files for views that use onClick (warning id: UsingOnClickInXml, older versions of the platform do not properly support resolving Android:onClick). These also show up in lint warnings when I run the code inspector. It appears that Android Studio doesn't use the minSdkVerion (16) that I set in my build.gradle (app) file.

```java
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Splash_PrivacyPolicy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick" //This gets highlighted with the warning
        android:text="@string/dialog_button_privacyPolicy"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        />
```

Here is an excerpt from my build.gradle (app) file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        ...
        }
    ...
}
```

This appears to be preserved in my merged AndroidManifest.xml (I'm not directly setting a minSdkVerion in the manifest, only in the build.gradle file). Excerpt from merged AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest
  ...
  <uses-sdk
    android.minSdkVersion="16"
    android.targetSdkVersion="30" />
  ...
```

Example of how I use onClick in the associated Activity :

```java
    public void onClick(View view){
        if (view.getId() == R.id.btn_SplashOK) {
            if (mCheckBox_SplashDontShowAgain.isChecked()) {
                sendIntentInfoBack(Constants.DONT_SHOW_AGAIN);
            } else {
                sendIntentInfoBack(Constants.DO_SHOW_AGAIN);
            }
        } else if (view.getId() == R.id.btn_Splash_PrivacyPolicy){
            Toolset.showPrivacyPolicyDialog(getSupportFragmentManager());
        }
    }
```

The app appears to function correctly, but I'm concerned AS / lint doesn't recognize the minSdkVersion I've set.

### I've tried:

1. Build->Clean Project
2. Build->Rebuild Project
3. Build->Make Project
4. File->Invalidate Caches/Restart
5. Changing minSdkVersion to 17, sync, change back to 16, sync
6. Re-running Analyze->Inspect Code several times

### I've reviewed:

[Android Studio not picking up the minSdkVersion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629902/android-studio-not-picking-up-the-minsdkversion) - not applicable; I've set the value in the correct file.

[Android Lint erroneously thinks min SDK version is 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322482/android-lint-erroneously-thinks-min-sdk-version-is-1) - not applicable? I was unable to find "Clear Lint Markers" in AS, per the answer; out of date? (answer from 2012)

## My Questions:

1. Is this a problem/should I be concerned?
2. Is there a way to fix AS / lint to accurately use the minSdkVersion I've set?

Comment: Please consider adding Android studio version you are working on.

Comment: @Zain, thanks for the suggestion. I've added it (version 4.1.1) to the write-up.

Comment: Did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Message "Using 'android:onClick' on older version of the platform is broken" appears from version androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0

Comment: I don't understand what you want to express. If you set minSdkVersion in build.gradle you shouldn't get warnings concerning a lower version.